# Selenium Check download link is active or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Using Java And selenium I want to check my  download link are live or not.I just want to show http status code.

```
      HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(baseUrl);
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
      System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

I tried this but not success.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this to work the way I want. I've used the .isEnabled() option as shown below using TestNG;

```
@Test
public void testProductNavBar(){
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).isEnabled());
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment.Suppose if I Going to  check link 
http://cdn.rentbyowner.com/sitemap/gz/site-map-0.xml.gz
here no option to get ID

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it and it is working fine for verifying status of the link. My code is here.

```
public static void verifyURLStatus(String URL) {

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        // verifying response code and The HttpStatus should be 200 if not,
        // increment invalid link count
        // We can also check for 404 status code like response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404
        int invalidLinksCount=0;
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
            invalidLinksCount++;
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

String URL="http://cdn.rentbyowner.com/sitemap/gz/site-map-0.xml.gz";
verifyURLStatus(URL);
```

Comment: I run this code and its open browser with URL but unfortunately it's not showing any output.No error showing on program but not getting output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can use httpurl connection to to validate the download link. Below is the reusable code.

```
public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl)
{
    try 
    {
       URL url = new URL(linkUrl);
       HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
       httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
       httpURLConnect.connect();
       if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==200)
       {
           System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println(linkUrl+" - is Dowm");
       }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks.